# Python regex search only finding the first pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I am using python's re module to search in a string for certain words.

For a simple example, I have a list called valid_words and a string called valid_string.

```
valid_string = "Use Use%"
valid_words = ['Use', 'Use%']

for header in valid_words:
  regex_search = re.search("\\b"+header+"\\b",  valid_string)
  if regex_search:
    print header
```

However, this only returns Use and not Use%. I think this is because the % in 'Use%' is being treated as a regular expression. Am I correct? Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using word boundaries, however, with your second word `'Use%'`, the word boundary actually occurs between `e` and `%`.  For example:

```
>>> re.search('.\\b','Use%').group(0)
'e'
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So is there a way to move the boundary to the end of each word in valid_words?

Comment: @Fsun -- It's hard to say what is best to do here.  It seems like a simple `str.split` would be what you want, but it's hard to say ...

Comment: Thank you. But, str.split actually isn't viable in my situation. For example, an element in valid_words may be "He llo", so the regex search will look for "He llo" in valid_string.